# Stuck - Favorite TV Show Logic grid

Tags: logic-grid

Four friends (Al, Gary, Mike, & Roger) each have a favorite TV show. Oddly enough, while the four are close friends, their interest in TV shows is so different that none of the friends has the same favorite. In fact, each favorite show (Explorer, FBI, Family Tides, & Z-Files) airs on a different night (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, & Wednesday) and at a different time (7pm, 8pm, 9pm or 10pm). Determine the name of each friend, the title of their favorite TV show, and the day of the week and time that the show airs.

1. The person who enjoyed the TV show, FBI, doesn’t watch it on Sunday night. The TV show, Explorer, aired at 7 pm, but it wasn’t Mike’s favorite show.
2. Family Tides wasn’t Al’s favorite TV show.
3. Roger’s favorite TV show aired at 10 pm, but not on Wednesday night.
4. The TV show that aired on Tuesday night is The Z-Files.
5. Mike doesn’t watch a TV show at 9 pm. Gary doesn’t watch TV on Sunday night.
6. The TV show, Family Tides, aired an hour after the show that Gary liked but an hour before the show that aired on Monday night.

Source: https://slideplayer.com/slide/8573924/

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please take the [tour](/tour). Is this a puzzle you found elsewhere? If so, please provide attribution.

Comment: Hi @user65792, welcome to Puzzling SE! I see you have provided proper attribution for your question, but instead of reposting it, you should edit in the information onto the original post so that we can review and reopen it. I’ve done this for you already, but keep that in mind in the future if this ever happens again. I hope this helps!

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> Explorer  -  Gary   - Wednesday -  7pm.
>  FBI          -  Al     - Monday    -  9pm.
>  Family Tides -  Mike   - Sunday    -  8pm.
>  Z-Files      -  Roger  - Tuesday   - 10pm.
>
>  Process:
>  Family Tides either airs at 8pm or 9pm (statement 6). Al's favorite isn't FT, Roger likes the 10pm show & FT airs an hour after the show Gary likes, so we can conclude Mike's favorite is FT. FT has to air at 8pm (statement 5). Gary's favorite has to be the 7pm show which is Explorer. Monday show airs at 9pm and Roger watches 10pm show, not on a Wednesday. We can conclude that Roger's favorite is the 10pm show on Tuesday (Z-Files). Al watches 9pm show FBI on Monday. Since Gary doesn't watch a show on Sunday, Explorer airs on Wednesday 7pm & FT airs on Sunday 8pm.

Answer (score 0):

This question can be solved that way:

> [image: picture]

Answer (score -1):

The answer is:

> `Family Tides -  Mike   - Sunday    -  8pm
>  Z-Files      -  Roger  - Tuesday   - 10pm
>  Explorer     -  Gary   - Wednesday -  7pm
>  FBI          -  Al     - Monday    -  9pm`

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I can understand your process?

Comment: Can you explain how you got this answer? Note that answers without explanation on this site tend to be [deleted](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1493/57742), so you may want to put one in to avoid that from happening

Comment: I just used the very same table I am showing as answer and kept fullfiling by writing !sunday, monday/tuesday etc... as the whitelisted/blacklisted combinations. At the beginning it had 3 or 4 extra rows because of conditions that worked on different dimensions, I just got them merged one by one by checking the logic. The key one is the one that says an hour before X but an hour after Y, theres a lot of combinations removed in there. But the proper way to solve this problems (I loved them as child) is using a binary table such as: http://www.zugarto.com/files/juegosdelogica.jpg.

Comment: Theres some rules when you write there an O or a X, like when you have 3 vertexs  of O's that compose an square, the 4th one is automatically inferred

Comment: @user65573 Please add your commentary here to your answer, as comments are ephemeral and the _answer_ without the explanation isn't complete.